# how to recreate the data into user when the users already created

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

hello there hopefully you can help me with this problem. i dont know if this possible when the user was already created and want to loop the all user id when the teacher create another subject and add that subject on their schedule.. so here is my problem i will explain

i created a student with grade , room and subject

output

```
student_id | grade  | room | subject 
1          | 1st yr | rose | math
1          | 1st yr | rose | english
```

so the student 1 had created and has a subject math and english in **1st year** and **rose** room.

what if the teacher want to create or add a subject **Music** and **student** on that 1st year and rose room. lets say the teacher already added those two. so expecting output is like this

```
student_id | grade  | room | subject 
2          | 1st yr | rose | math
2          | 1st yr | rose | english
2          | 1st yr | rose | music
```

after created a student and subject the overall output on that table

```
student_id | grade  | room | subject 
1          | 1st yr | rose | math
1          | 1st yr | rose | english

2          | 1st yr | rose | math
2          | 1st yr | rose | english
2          | 1st yr | rose | music
```

now the problem is the **student 1** have no **music** subject.
and the question is how to add that subject **music** on the **student 1**
if was already created by teacher.

Comment: If these tables are tables in the database you should definitely read upon normalization!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a new subject to a specific room what you can do is:

1. Get a list of all the distinct students in that room.
2. Get a list of all the subjects each student has.
3. If a student doesn't have the recently added subject, add it.

Although, in terms of data structure your database is not really benefiting from Entities and Relationships.

From what you are showing I suppose you are new to the subject of databases. In simple terms what I would do is the following.

- A **Rooms** table where you can store all the distinct rooms.
- A **Subjects** table where you can store all the distinct subjects.
- A **Students** table where you can store all the specific student data.
- A relationship table **SubjectsPerRoom** where you can connect subjects to rooms. This way you can easily define which room has which subjects.
- A relationship table **SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom** where you basically make the connection between the 3 entities. This one is a little redundant if you have the **SubjectsPerRoom** table, but you can use it for exceptions when specific students can have or not have a certain subject.

A diagram example would look like this:
[image: Example ER diagram]

So for example, if you want to add a new **Subject** you'd have to do something like.

```sql
INSERT INTO `Rooms` (room_name) VALUES ('rose');
```

Let's suppose this returns ID=1

```sql
INSERT INTO `Subjects` (subject_name) VALUES ('music');
```

Let's suppose this returns ID=34. Then you assign it to the room 1

```sql
INSERT INTO `SubjectsPerRoom` (subject_id, room_id) VALUES (34, 1);
```

Now you know that the subject **music** is assigned to the room **rose**. If you later add another room or another subject you can use this same query and just create the relation between those entities. This way you only have one instance of each room and you don't repeat information you just relate things between each other. As commented on your question this is normalization of data.

Then, let's say you add 3 students:

```sql
INSERT INTO `Students` (student_name) VALUES ('Tom');
INSERT INTO `Students` (student_name) VALUES ('Jerry');
INSERT INTO `Students` (student_name) VALUES ('Butch');
```

Let's suppose those return IDs 1, 2 and 3.

Now, you have 1 room, 1 subject and 3 students. The only thing left is to create a relationship between **student**, **room** and **subject**.

```sql
INSERT INTO SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom (student_id, subject_id, room_id) VALUES (1, 34, 1);
INSERT INTO SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom (student_id, subject_id, room_id) VALUES (2, 34, 1);
INSERT INTO SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom (student_id, subject_id, room_id) VALUES (3, 34, 1);
```

Now you know that there are three students assigned to room **rose** to subject **music**.

Then, if you add let's say a new subject as you are asking. You would do the following steps:

1. Create subject.
2. Assign it to room.
3. Select all students assigned to room **rose**.
4. For each existing student, assigned to room **rose**, add new relationship with new subject.

```sql
INSERT INTO `Subjects` (subject_name) VALUES ('english');
```

Let's suppose this returns 35

```sql
INSERT INTO `SubjectsPerRoom` (subject_id, room_id) VALUES (35, 1);
```

Since you have not added new students to that room and you just created and assigned the subject to that room, then you just need to create the relationship between the room.

```php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom WHERE `room_id` = 1';

// run your query and let's say the info is assigned to $students

foreach($students as $student) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom (student_id, subject_id, room_id) VALUES ($student->student_id, 35, 1);';
}
```

And then if you want to select the students assigned to a particular class in a particular room you can do this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom
JOIN Students ON Students.student_id = SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom.student_id
WHERE SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom.room_id = 1 AND SubjectsPerStudentPerRoom.subject_id = 35
```

This would give you all students assigned to room **rose** and subject **english**.

Hope this helps you achieve what you're looking for.

PS: This is simplified on purpose, but it should lead you in the right direction.